# doublesecretagency business logic module template: 404 on example form action

Tags: controller

I set up the business logic module template following these instructions:
https://doublesecretagency.github.io/craft-businesslogic/installation

The test works out well, so everything seems to be in order.

However, when I add the example action to a form and submit it, I get a 404:

Unable to resolve the request "business-logic/example/example-form-submit".

How do I find and fix the underlying issue?

EDIT: I tried setting up a module via https://pluginfactory.io/ and that works like a charm.

Comment: Are you logged in or logged out when you are submitting the form? Perhaps try enabling [anonymous access...](https://github.com/doublesecretagency/craft-businesslogic/blob/master/src/controllers/ExampleController.php#L39)

Comment: Hi Lindsey, yes I am logged in as admin user. Even when enabling anonymous access it returns a 404. I've managed to solve my problem using the pluginfactory, but I wonder whether anything is wrong with the craft-businesslogic.

Comment: Very strange. I am the author of the Business Logic template, and everything you've posted looks like it should work as intended. I'm glad you got a solution worked out with pluginfactory.io! If you'd still like me to address the Business Logic issue, feel free to [post it on Github](https://github.com/doublesecretagency/craft-businesslogic/issues).

Comment: Thanks Lindsey. In the end I figured out a way to get what I needed without using a module, since I couldn't get the php/craft code working (I don't know anything about that so was a bit lost).

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to be quite simple: the module is referenced incorrectly in the example code. The example action-input is:

`<input type="hidden" name="action" value="business-logic/example/example-form-submit">`

but it should be:

`<input type="hidden" name="action" value="businesslogic/example/example-form-submit">`

Omitting the dash in the "business-logic" name, since the module is being loaded as "businesslogic" instead.

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember to add the action as a hidden input (`<input type="hidden" name="action" value="business-logic/example/example-form-submit">`, rather than an `action` attribute on the form? And also use `method="post"` on the form.

Comment: Yes, it's set up like that and I've tried via the {{ actionInput() }} as well.